# Polynomial division of $\dfrac{a^2+ad+ac+cd-2ab-2bd}{a^2-ad-ac+cd} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I were to attempt polynomial division on this expression:

$\dfrac{a^2+ad+ac+cd-2ab-2bd}{a^2-ad-ac+cd} $,

I would get $(a^2-ad-ac+cd)(1)+2ad+2ac-2ab-2bd$.

Where $2ad+2ac-2ab-2bd$ is the remainder.

Thus $(a^2-ad-ac+cd)(1)+2ad+2ac-2ab-2bd=a^2+ad+ac+cd-2ab-2bd$.

But writing down $\dfrac{a^2+ad+ac+cd-2ab-2bd}{a^2-ad-ac+cd} =a^2+ad+ac+cd-2ab-2bd$ doesn't make sense. Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If you have $W=XY+Z$, that gives you $\frac{W}{X}=Y+\frac{Z}{X}$ after division by $X$. You wrote $\frac{W}{X}=W$ instead.

Comment: why are you trying to perform polynomial division between two polynomials of the same degree?

Comment: @ColleganDelta Why wouldn't you? $\frac{x+2}{x+1}=1+\frac{1}{x+1}$. Even if the numerator were strictly smaller $\frac{2}{x+1}=0+\frac{2}{x+1}$. No problem.

Comment: I was just curious of the context, you can, but it is not always useful, e.g. if you are trying to simplify a fraction it is kinda pointless IMO

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Looks like a terrible logical fallacy on my part to commit this error.